# Creating .jar file with netbeans when heap size is increased using -xmx

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, runtime-error, heap-memory

I am new to java.I programmed my application in netbeans. Initially it was throwing error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

So, i used `-Xmx` option by right clicking the application->properties->Run->VMoption. 
Now the program runs perfectly fine in my IDE, but i am trying to make jar file which i will distribute . I have made .jar file by "clean and build project" in netbeans. It creates the .jar file in dist folder but that jar file is not working as it should work. I am not getting any output for this application. Though i tested for other application where `-xmx` parameter is not set, and it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone please tell me whats can be the issue?
Also, how can i create my .jar file for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But there are many workarounds. The application must be started with

```
java -Xmx512M -jar myJar.jar
```

So your options are to use a wrapper such as launch4j, or make a shortcut to the jar where you add this -Xmx parameter, or you can actually write a piece of code that is executed when you write java -jar myJar.jar that will read a jar inside your jar and run that with the proper parameters. This last option is semi difficult.

Here's a blogpost about the latter option: http://silentdevelopment.blogspot.dk/2010/03/how-to-set-or-increase-xmx-heap-memory.html

Comment: Thanx Xabster. Can you elaborate a bit on the last option. I am using windows 7 and there we have a tool "iexpress" which can convert a jar to exe. But for that i need .jar file. There we have an option named install program where we put java -jar myJar.jar. Can that be helpful to me somehow?

Comment: You can probably use that, yes. That would be the first option I mentioned (launch4j is an often mentioned jar-to-exe wrapper). Go ahead and try it. Edit: IExpress is just a helper for creating self-extracting zip files I guess. You can still use it to achieve your goal though.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. Can you give me some way to create .jar. I mean some ready code or steps. I am unable to understand whatever the link you given says. :( I have started my programming 5 days ago. So, please help.

Comment: You already created the jar file. If you wish to run that jar file you must run "java -Xmx512M -jar whateverjarfileyouhave.jar". If you hate re-writing that Xmx part of it you must either create a shortcut or use that IExpress or whatever you wish to do. You cannot simply doubly click it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Xabster. Can you tell me where to add "java -Xmx512M -jar myJar.jar" line in Launch4j GUI. Should i put it in command line args under basic tab? or somewhere else?

Comment: It would be a launch option/VM argument. I'm unsure where in the Launch4j GUI it is since it's been a while since I used it.

Comment: I googled, it's in the JRE tab under JVM options: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/irf_guide_java_friesen4/elementLinks/launch4j-fig03.jpg

Comment: Thanks man...thank you very much. That really helped me to do my task.  :)